# Issue nesting mappings in react with arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have data that is structured in object and I want to nest mappings in the react return function to render workkouts based on a selected date.

here is the data that I am working with:

```
[  
   {  
      "date":"Saturday, May 11th",
      "workouts":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "full":true,
            "difficulty":"Open",
            "time":"1:15pm",
            "nbr_rounds":10,
            "trainer":"Tommy Duquette"
         },
         {  
            "id":2,
            "full":true,
            "difficulty":"Intermediate",
            "time":"2:45pm",
            "nbr_rounds":4,
            "trainer":"Tommy Duquette"
         },
         {  
            "id":3,
            "full":false,
            "difficulty":"Intermediate",
            "time":"3:30pm",
            "nbr_rounds":4,
            "trainer":"Tommy Duquette"
         },
         {  
            "id":4,
            "full":false,
            "difficulty":"Open",
            "time":"4:20pm",
            "nbr_rounds":8,
            "trainer":"Tommy Duquette"
         },
         {  
            "id":5,
            "full":false,
            "difficulty":"Open",
            "time":"5:20pm",
            "nbr_rounds":8,
            "trainer":"Tommy Duquette"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "date":"Sunday, May 12th",
      "workouts":[  
         {  
            "id":6,
            "full":true,
            "difficulty":"Open",
            "time":"1:15pm",
            "nbr_rounds":10,
            "trainer":"Tommy Duquette"
         },
         {  
            "id":7,
            "full":false,
            "difficulty":"Intermediate",
            "time":"2:45pm",
            "nbr_rounds":4,
            "trainer":"Tommy Duquette"
         },
         {  
            "id":8,
            "full":false,
            "difficulty":"Open",
            "time":"3:30pm",
            "nbr_rounds":4,
            "trainer":"Tommy Duquette"
         },
         {  
            "id":9,
            "full":true,
            "difficulty":"Intermediate",
            "time":"4:20pm",
            "trainer":"Tommy Duquette"
         },
         {  
            "id":10,
            "full":false,
            "difficulty":"Open",
            "time":"5:20pm",
            "nbr_rounds":8,
            "trainer":"Tommy Duquette"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to look through and see if the object date matches the selected date that is passed in as a prop. I then want to map and render the workouts based on the date matching.

This is my code:

```
export default function ClassList(props){
    return(
        <div>
            {
                props.data.map((data) => {
                    if(data.date === props.selectedDate){
                        <div>
                        {
                            data.workouts.map((class) => {
                                return(
                                    <div>
                                        {class.full}
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                        </div>
                    }
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
};
```

I am getting a parsing error on the second mapping function:

```
./src/components/classList.jsx
  Line 11:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "{"

   9 |                         <div>
  10 |                         {
> 11 |                             data.workouts.map((class) => {
     |                                                     ^
  12 |                                 return(
  13 |                                     <div>
  14 |                                         {class.full}
```

Answer (score 2):

`class` is a reserved word in javascript so you should try a different 
variable name instead of `class`

Aka, change this

```
data.workouts.map((class) => {
-------------------^---^
```

to this:

```
data.workouts.map((workout) => {
```